# How can I declare a variable with name 'operator'?

Tags: c#

How can I declare a variable with name "operator"?

```cs
public string operator;
```

[image: I see the below error, click here to see the picture]

Comment: `@operator` should work. I'd recommend not using keywords as identifiers though.

Comment: nb : could you please copy-paste (and format) the interesting part of the error message as text into your question ? This is much better for searchability and [many other reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/479251)

Comment: Synonyms for operator: 
driver
engineer
operative
operant

Answer (score 3):

you can use any reserved word by prefixing the name of your identifier with an `@` : `@operator`

```
var @operator = "+";
var @event = new { name = "Burning man" };
var @var = 23;
var @enum = new List { 1, 2, 3 };
```

needless to say, this is not so much helping readability, but if you feel it fits your case, you can use it.

Answer (score 2):

Use `public string @operator`.

The @ prefix allows you to use reserved words as variable names.